# How can I generate random seed for new account of web3js?

Tags: web3js

I had created wallet account using web3.eth.accounts.wallet.create(). Now I want to generate random seed for that address. So which method of web3js will be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [bip39](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bip39) npm package to generate your random mnemonic. Then using same package convert the mnemonic to seed and use [ethereumjs-wallet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-wallet). Or you can use the truffle's hdwalletprovider to use the mnemonic as such.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I want to use without npm package because I have to use it in Magento2 and in magento2 npm module conflicts with requireJs. So have you any other solutions or examples of it?

Comment: how did you install web3 js

Comment: npm install web3 --save for npm and also I used directly cdn